# Vary keyboard region per device

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I'm UK based running Windows 10 on multiple devices, one of which has a US keyboard; all the other devices have UK keyboards. Changing the keyboard to US affects all my devices and changing it back to UK on any other device (including Windows phone) sets all devices to UK, including the one with a US keyboard attached to it. It's almost as if the setting is per user rather than per device which is annoying in my case: does anyone know how to configure the keyboard per device on Windows 10?

Comment: Try turning off sync of _Language preferences_ [How to Turn On or Off Sync Your Settings in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4077-sync-settings-turn-off-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: Good find! I've switched it off and will post back here later with the result later.

Comment: Could this [`OneDrive` settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/sync-settings-pcs)  work  on Windows 10 as well? Check http://www.howtogeek.com/222110/understanding-the-new-sync-settings-in-windows-10/

Comment: @DavidPostill the setting stops the PC with the US keyboard from pushing the setting to the other PCs *but* the PC with the US keyboard still picks up the setting from the other PCs. So it half works: the other PCs are no longer getting changed to US keyboard, the PC with the US keyboard still reverts back to UK keyboard all the time.

Comment: @qujck You need to turn off that setting on the other devices as well ...

Comment: @DavidPostill sadly the phone does not offer the same level of granularity as the desktop.

Comment: @qujck I meant the other PCs